# Найти одинаковые значения ключей

Tags: jquery, json, объекты

Помогите с циклом. Туплю. Есть объект:

```
{
    'done': true,
    'brands': {
        'models': [
            {
                'id': 0,
                'brands': [
                    {
                        'mod': [
                            {
                                'brand_name': 'audi_a8_long'
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        'mod': [
                            {
                                'brand_name': 'audi_a4'
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        'mod': [
                            {
                                'brand_name': 'porsche_911'
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                'id': 1,
                'brands': [
                    {
                        'mod': [
                            {
                                'brand_name': 'jaguar_xjr'
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        'mod': [
                            {
                                'brand_name': 'jaguar_xjr'
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        'mod': [
                            {
                                'brand_name': 'audi_a8_long'
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        'mod': [
                            {
                                'brand_name': 'audi_a6'
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

суть такая, есть объект `cars`, в котором есть ключ `models` с массивами объектов `brands`, этих объектов `brands` неизвестное количество, то есть может быть 1 или овер 9999999. в каждом `brands` есть массив с объектом `mod` в котором n-brand_names. Нужно вывести в консоль содержимое этого ужаса в формате: `audi_a8_long - 2шт, jaguar_xjr -1 шт` и так далее. то есть даже количество `mod` и `brand_names` неизвестно. Это ответ от сервера. я уже третий день пытаюсь что-то сделать с циклами. но выходит только выводит в консоль список в виде `audi_a8_long - 1, audi_a8_long - 1, jaguar_xjr-1`, и так далее, то есть вывожу как баран каждый `brand_name` отдельно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Ещё более новый ответ (30.05.2017 12:25)

```js
let object = {
    'done': true,
    'guid_image': {
        'raw_bbox': [
            {
                'bbox': [
                    2017,
                    1583,
                    2412,
                    2836,
                    0,
                    -1
                ],

                'id': '211'

            },
            {
                'bbox': [
                    688,
                    462,
                    1023,
                    1506,
                    1,
                    -1
                ],

                'id': '27'

            },
            {
                'bbox': [
                    1763,
                    448,
                    2071,
                    1586,
                    2,
                    -1
                ],

                'id': '27'
            },
            {
                'bbox': [
                    1715,
                    1597,
                    2052,
                    2723,
                    3,
                    -1
                ],

                'id': '36'
            },
            {
                'bbox': [
                    980,
                    461,
                    1271,
                    1499,
                    4,
                    -1
                ],

                'id': '27'
            },
            {
                'bbox': [
                    1226,
                    473,
                    1522,
                    1528,
                    5,
                    -1
                ],

                'id': '27'
            },
            {
                'bbox': [
                    139,
                    437,
                    506,
                    1484,
                    6,
                    -1
                ],

                'id': '27'

            },
            {
                'bbox': [
                    412,
                    448,
                    728,
                    1484,
                    7,
                    -1
                ],

                'id': '27'
            }
            ,
            {
                'bbox': [
                    2043,
                    507,
                    2324,
                    1513,
                    8,
                    -1
                ],

                'id': '35'
            },
            {
                'bbox': [
                    1490,
                    444,
                    1824,
                    1529,
                    9,
                    -1
                ],

                'id': '27'
            },
            {
                'bbox': [
                    1406,
                    1621,
                    1746,
                    2695,
                    10,
                    -1
                ],

                'id': '36'
            },
            {
                'bbox': [
                    656,
                    1627,
                    1028,
                    2721,
                    11,
                    -1
                ],

                'id': '28'
            },
            {
                'bbox': [
                    1104,
                    1631,
                    1423,
                    2707,
                    12,
                    -1
                ],

                'id': '28'

            },
            {
                'bbox': [
                    338,
                    1599,
                    674,
                    2693,
                    13,
                    -1
                ],

                'id': '28'
            },
            {
                'bbox': [
                    51,
                    1722,
                    352,
                    2703,
                    14,
                    -1
                ],

                'id': '218'

            }
        ],
        'shelfs': [
            {
                'bbox': [
                    0.0,
                    437.0,
                    2448.0,
                    1586.0
                ],
                'id': 0,
                'mean_width': null,
                'places': [
                    {
                        'amount': 1,
                        'bbox': [
                            139,
                            437,
                            506,
                            1484
                        ],
                        'id': 0,
                        'skus': [
                            {
                                'bbox': [
                                    139,
                                    437,
                                    506,
                                    1484,
                                    6,
                                    -1
                                ],
                                'brand_name': 'ferrari_ff',
                                'confidence_complex': 0.99997,
                                'confidence_id_cch_category': 1.0,
                                'confidence_id_cch_cco': 1.0,
                                'confidence_id_cch_sku': 1.0

                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        'amount': 1,
                        'bbox': [
                            412,
                            448,
                            728,
                            1484
                        ],
                        'id': 1,
                        'skus': [
                            {
                                'bbox': [
                                    412,
                                    448,
                                    728,
                                    1484,
                                    7,
                                    -1
                                ],
                                'brand_name': 'bmw_525',
                                'confidence_complex': 0.99997,
                                'confidence_id_cch_category': 1.0,
                                'confidence_id_cch_cco': 1.0,
                                'confidence_id_cch_sku': 1.0

                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        'amount': 1,
                        'bbox': [
                            688,
                            462,
                            1023,
                            1506
                        ],
                        'id': 2,
                        'skus': [
                            {
                                'bbox': [
                                    688,
                                    462,
                                    1023,
                                    1506,
                                    1,
                                    -1
                                ],
                                'brand_name': 'bmw_m3',
                                'confidence_complex': 0.99999,
                                'confidence_id_cch_category': 1.0,
                                'confidence_id_cch_cco': 1.0,
                                'confidence_id_cch_sku': 1.0

                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        'amount': 1,
                        'bbox': [
                            980,
                            461,
                            1271,
                            1499
                        ],
                        'id': 3,
                        'skus': [
                            {
                                'bbox': [
                                    980,
                                    461,
                                    1271,
                                    1499,
                                    4,
                                    -1
                                ],
                                'brand_name': 'audi_a3',
                                'confidence_complex': 0.99999,
                                'confidence_id_cch_category': 1.0,
                                'confidence_id_cch_cco': 1.0,
                                'confidence_id_cch_sku': 1.0

                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        'amount': 1,
                        'bbox': [
                            1226,
                            473,
                            1522,
                            1528
                        ],
                        'id': 4,
                        'skus': [
                            {
                                'bbox': [
                                    1226,
                                    473,
                                    1522,
                                    1528,
                                    5,
                                    -1
                                ],
                                'brand_name': 'audi_a3',
                                'confidence_complex': 1.0,
                                'confidence_id_cch_category': 1.0,
                                'confidence_id_cch_cco': 1.0,
                                'confidence_id_cch_sku': 1.0

                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        'amount': 1,
                        'bbox': [
                            1490,
                            444,
                            1824,
                            1529
                        ],
                        'id': 5,
                        'skus': [
                            {
                                'bbox': [
                                    1490,
                                    444,
                                    1824,
                                    1529,
                                    9,
                                    -1
                                ],
                                'brand_name': 'bmw_525',
                                'confidence_complex': 0.99999,
                                'confidence_id_cch_category': 1.0,
                                'confidence_id_cch_cco': 1.0,
                                'confidence_id_cch_sku': 1.0

                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        'amount': 1,
                        'bbox': [
                            1763,
                            448,
                            2071,
                            1586
                        ],
                        'id': 6,
                        'skus': [
                            {
                                'bbox': [
                                    1763,
                                    448,
                                    2071,
                                    1586,
                                    2,
                                    -1
                                ],
                                'brand_name': 'audi_a8_long',
                                'confidence_complex': 0.99999,
                                'confidence_id_cch_category': 1.0,
                                'confidence_id_cch_cco': 1.0,
                                'confidence_id_cch_sku': 1.0

                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        'amount': 1,
                        'bbox': [
                            2043,
                            507,
                            2324,
                            1513
                        ],
                        'id': 7,
                        'skus': [
                            {
                                'bbox': [
                                    2043,
                                    507,
                                    2324,
                                    1513,
                                    8,
                                    -1
                                ],
                                'brand_name': 'audi_a1',
                                'confidence_complex': 0.99999,
                                'confidence_id_cch_category': 1.0,
                                'confidence_id_cch_sku': 1.0

                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                'bbox': [
                    0.0,
                    1583.0,
                    2448.0,
                    2836.0
                ],
                'id': 1,
                'mean_width': null,
                'places': [
                    {
                        'amount': 1,
                        'bbox': [
                            51,
                            1722,
                            352,
                            2703
                        ],
                        'id': 0,
                        'skus': [
                            {
                                'bbox': [
                                    51,
                                    1722,
                                    352,
                                    2703,
                                    14,
                                    -1
                                ],
                                'brand_name': 'other_ssd',
                                'confidence_id_cch_category': 0.93
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        'amount': 1,
                        'bbox': [
                            338,
                            1599,
                            674,
                            2693
                        ],
                        'id': 1,
                        'skus': [
                            {
                                'bbox': [
                                    338,
                                    1599,
                                    674,
                                    2693,
                                    13,
                                    -1
                                ],
                                'brand_name': 'bmw_525',
                                'confidence_complex': 0.99999,
                                'confidence_id_cch_category': 1.0,
                                'confidence_id_cch_cco': 1.0,
                                'confidence_id_cch_sku': 1.0

                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        'amount': 1,
                        'bbox': [
                            656,
                            1627,
                            1028,
                            2721
                        ],
                        'id': 2,
                        'skus': [
                            {
                                'bbox': [
                                    656,
                                    1627,
                                    1028,
                                    2721,
                                    11,
                                    -1
                                ],
                                'brand_name': 'jaguar_xjr',
                                'confidence_complex': 1.0,
                                'confidence_id_cch_category': 1.0,
                                'confidence_id_cch_cco': 1.0,
                                'confidence_id_cch_sku': 1.0

                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        'amount': 1,
                        'bbox': [
                            1104,
                            1631,
                            1423,
                            2707
                        ],
                        'id': 3,
                        'skus': [
                            {
                                'bbox': [
                                    1104,
                                    1631,
                                    1423,
                                    2707,
                                    12,
                                    -1
                                ],
                                'brand_name': 'bmw_m3',
                                'confidence_complex': 0.99999,
                                'confidence_id_cch_category': 1.0,
                                'confidence_id_cch_cco': 1.0,
                                'confidence_id_cch_sku': 1.0

                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        'amount': 1,
                        'bbox': [
                            1406,
                            1621,
                            1746,
                            2695
                        ],
                        'id': 4,
                        'skus': [
                            {
                                'bbox': [
                                    1406,
                                    1621,
                                    1746,
                                    2695,
                                    10,
                                    -1
                                ],
                                'brand_name': 'audi_a1',
                                'confidence_complex': 1.0,
                                'confidence_id_cch_category': 1.0,
                                'confidence_id_cch_sku': 1.0

                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        'amount': 1,
                        'bbox': [
                            1715,
                            1597,
                            2052,
                            2723
                        ],
                        'id': 5,
                        'skus': [
                            {
                                'bbox': [
                                    1715,
                                    1597,
                                    2052,
                                    2723,
                                    3,
                                    -1
                                ],
                                'brand_name': 'bmw_m3',
                                'confidence_complex': 1.0,
                                'confidence_id_cch_category': 1.0,
                                'confidence_id_cch_sku': 1.0

                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        'amount': 1,
                        'bbox': [
                            2017,
                            1583,
                            2412,
                            2836
                        ],
                        'id': 6,
                        'skus': [
                            {
                                'bbox': [
                                    2017,
                                    1583,
                                    2412,
                                    2836,
                                    0,
                                    -1
                                ],
                                'brand_name': 'audi_a1',
                                'confidence_complex': 0.989604,
                                'confidence_id_cch_category': 1.0,
                                'confidence_id_cch_sku': 0.99,
                                'confidence_id_cch_so': 0.54

                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
};

let numbersOfBrands = {};
function addBrand(brand) {
    if (!(brand in numbersOfBrands)) {
        numbersOfBrands[brand] = 0;
    }
    ++numbersOfBrands[brand];
}

let array = object.guid_image.shelfs;
for (let element1 of array) {
    for (let element2 of element1.places) {
        for (let element3 of element2.skus) {
            addBrand(element3.brand_name);
        }
    }
}

for (let brand of Object.keys(numbersOfBrands)) {
    console.log(`бренд ${brand} --- ${numbersOfBrands[brand]} штук`);
}
console.log('Суммарное число:' + Object.values(numbersOfBrands).reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0));
```

## Новый ответ:

Здесь могут помочь функции [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) и цикл [`for..of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of). Советую прочитать статьи по ссылкам.

Возможная реализация:

```js
let object = {
    'done': true,
    'brands': {
        'models': [
            {
                'id': 0,
                'brands': [
                    {
                        'mod': [
                            {
                                'brand_name': 'audi_a8_long'
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        'mod': [
                            {
                                'brand_name': 'audi_a4'
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        'mod': [
                            {
                                'brand_name': 'porsche_911'
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                'id': 1,
                'brands': [
                    {
                        'mod': [
                            {
                                'brand_name': 'jaguar_xjr'
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        'mod': [
                            {
                                'brand_name': 'jaguar_xjr'
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        'skus': [
                            {
                                'brand_name': 'audi_a8_long'
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        'skus': [
                            {
                                'brand_name': 'audi_a6'
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
};

let numbersOfBrands = {};
function addBrand(brand) {
    if (!(brand in numbersOfBrands)) {
        numbersOfBrands[brand] = 0;
    }
    ++numbersOfBrands[brand];
}

let array = object.brands.models;
for (let model of array) {
    for (let brand of model.brands) {
        for (let element of Object.values(brand)) {
            for (let elementInner of element) {
                addBrand(elementInner.brand_name);
            }
        }
    }
}

for (let brand of Object.keys(numbersOfBrands)) {
    console.log(`бренд ${brand} --- ${numbersOfBrands[brand]} штук`);
}
```

## Старый ответ:

В javascript объекты не могут иметь одинаковых ключей. Иными словами, все ключи объекта уникальны. Скорее всего у вас есть массив. К сожалению, из-за проблемы нескольких ключей ваше описание не очень понятно, однако могу предложить решение в случае, если исходный объект имеет вид

```
let array = [
    {brand: 'Ауди А5'},
    {brand: 'Ауди А3'},
    {brand: 'Ауди А5'},
    {brand: 'БМВ 5'}
];
```

Код:

```js
let array = [
    {brand: 'Ауди А5'},
    {brand: 'Ауди А3'},
    {brand: 'Ауди А5'},
    {brand: 'БМВ 5'}
];

let numbersOfBrands = {};
for (let element of array) {
    if (!(element.brand in numbersOfBrands)) {
        numbersOfBrands[element.brand] = 0;
    }
    ++numbersOfBrands[element.brand];
}

for (let brand of Object.keys(numbersOfBrands)) {
    console.log(`бренд ${brand} --- ${numbersOfBrands[brand]} штук`);
}
```

Для объекта выше будет выведено:

```
бренд Ауди А5 --- 2 штук
бренд Ауди А3 --- 1 штук
бренд БМВ 5 --- 1 штук
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59911/discussion-on-answer-by-----).